# Create a django superuser but never let it login

Tags: django, django-admin

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Create default system user without login authorization'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        User.objects.create_superuser('codobot', 's@codium.co', None)
```

I create the superuser with `None` password
But when I look into the database it still has data in field `password`.
 Begin with `!`

**Question:**
Is that user be able to login?

Comment: If you want create user and don't let him login you can use *is_active* set this to False and user can't be able to login to your system(if you using Django auth model).

Comment: First at all **None** can also have a hash value, but it get set to an unusable password if django detects None as raw_password, so thats the answer why data is in the password field. The **!** is just caused by the secret key hash combo I guess.

Comment: @Thaian. Thank you for your reply. Just realize your answer is one of my option too

Comment: @zypro That's the point. In the `Unix` world hashed password begins with `!` is mean not allowed to login. But later on many people prefer explicit way to put the `/bin/nologin` instead of the old style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the user can not login,

you can simple verified it:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

user = authenticate(username='codobot', password=None)
print ('Could not  login') if user is None else ('User is logged in')
```

by docs

> When the raw_password is None, the password will be set to an unusable password, as if set_unusable_password() were used.

details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#methods)

Comment: Please wait 3 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate
It use with `request` How do you know it can be used with my case?

Comment: Ahh. **credential. My bad

Answer (score 1):

When you call [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) or [`create_superuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser) with `password=None`, Django will call [`set_unusable_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password).

This sets a password which will never be accepted. Note that this isn't the same as a blank password `''`.